# Open file from the VS Code terminal window

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the Remote - SSH (VS Code) extension to connect to a server. In the VS Code terminal window I then sudo to a different user and navigate to a directory containing my file. Can I then open this file in VS Code via a command in the terminal? NOTE: I can't SSH directly to the server with the sudo user.

Comment: Try typing `code <path to file>` in the terminal?

Comment: because you need to sudo to a different user to read the file, VSC running under the previous user has no rights to read the file

Comment: Any other extensions that might help?

Comment: code <path to file> doesn't work. The terminal  is essentially a linux command line

Comment: Maybe do the path to VSCode executable followed by the path to the file then - so something like `/path/to/Vscode.exe /path/to/file`.  But I am wondering if what rioV8 said will stop you